# How to save video using web cam?

Tags: javascript, php, html, webcam

I have a plug & play web cam and i want to record video by clicking start and stop button. My web cam is iball company and if there are any simple script then please provide me. I want simple php code.

```
<p><video id="video" autoplay="autoplay"></video></p>
<p><input type="button" id="buttonSnap" value="Take screenshot" disabled="disabled" onclick="snapshot()" /></p>
<p>
<input type="button" id="buttonStart" value="Start" disabled="disabled" onclick="start()" />
<input type="button" id="buttonStop" value="Stop" disabled="disabled" onclick="stop()" />
</p>
<p><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></p>


<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var videoStream = null;
var preLog = document.getElementById('preLog');

function log(text)
{
    if (preLog) preLog.textContent += ('\n' + text);
    else alert(text);
}

function snapshot()
{
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
}

function noStream()
{
    log('Access to camera was denied!');
}

function stop()
{
    var myButton = document.getElementById('buttonStop');
    if (myButton) myButton.disabled = true;
    myButton = document.getElementById('buttonSnap');
    if (myButton) myButton.disabled = true;
    if (videoStream)
    {
        if (videoStream.stop) videoStream.stop();
        else if (videoStream.msStop) videoStream.msStop();
        videoStream.onended = null;
        videoStream = null;
    }
    if (video)
    {
        video.onerror = null;
        video.pause();
        if (video.mozSrcObject)
            video.mozSrcObject = null;
        video.src = "";
    }
    myButton = document.getElementById('buttonStart');
    if (myButton) myButton.disabled = false;
}

function gotStream(stream)
{
    var myButton = document.getElementById('buttonStart');
    if (myButton) myButton.disabled = true;
    videoStream = stream;
    log('Got stream.');
    video.onerror = function ()
    {
        log('video.onerror');
        if (video) stop();
    };
    stream.onended = noStream;
    if (window.webkitURL) video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    else if (video.mozSrcObject !== undefined)
    {//FF18a
        video.mozSrcObject = stream;
        video.play();
    }
    else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia)
    {//FF16a, 17a
        video.src = stream;
        video.play();
    }
    else if (window.URL) video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    else video.src = stream;
    myButton = document.getElementById('buttonSnap');
    if (myButton) myButton.disabled = false;
    myButton = document.getElementById('buttonStop');
    if (myButton) myButton.disabled = false;
}

function start()
{
    if ((typeof window === 'undefined') || (typeof navigator === 'undefined')) log('This page needs a Web browser with the objects window.* and navigator.*!');
    else if (!(video && canvas)) log('HTML context error!');
    else
    {
        log('Get user media…');
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) navigator.getUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream, noStream);
        else if (navigator.oGetUserMedia) navigator.oGetUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream, noStream);
        else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) navigator.mozGetUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream, noStream);
        else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream, noStream);
        else if (navigator.msGetUserMedia) navigator.msGetUserMedia({video:true, audio:false}, gotStream, noStream);
        else log('getUserMedia() not available from your Web browser!');
    }
}

start();
</script>
```

I got this code from https://codepen.io/blaberus/pen/raGdBG . Using This code I can see video but how can I record.
Anyone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta id="theme-color" name="theme-color" content="#fff">
<base target="_blank">
<title>Media Recorder API Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<style>
a#downloadLink {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    min-height: 1.2em;
}
p#data {
    min-height: 6em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div style = "text-align:center;">
    <h1>Media Recorder API Demo </h1>
    <!-- <h2>Record a 640x480 video using the media recorder API implemented in Firefox and Chrome</h2> -->
    <video controls autoplay></video><br>
    <button id="rec" onclick="onBtnRecordClicked()">Record</button>
    <button id="pauseRes"   onclick="onPauseResumeClicked()" disabled>Pause</button>
    <button id="stop"  onclick="onBtnStopClicked()" disabled>Stop</button>
 </div>
<a id="downloadLink" download="mediarecorder.webm" name="mediarecorder.webm" href></a>
<p id="data"></p>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
'use strict';

/* globals MediaRecorder */

// Spec is at http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dap/raw-file/tip/media-stream-capture/RecordingProposal.html

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;


if(getBrowser() == "Chrome"){
    var constraints = {"audio": true, "video": {  "mandatory": {  "minWidth": 640,  "maxWidth": 640, "minHeight": 480,"maxHeight": 480 }, "optional": [] } };//Chrome
}else if(getBrowser() == "Firefox"){
    var constraints = {audio: true,video: {  width: { min: 640, ideal: 640, max: 640 },  height: { min: 480, ideal: 480, max: 480 }}}; //Firefox
}

var recBtn = document.querySelector('button#rec');
var pauseResBtn = document.querySelector('button#pauseRes');
var stopBtn = document.querySelector('button#stop');

var videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
var dataElement = document.querySelector('#data');
var downloadLink = document.querySelector('a#downloadLink');

videoElement.controls = false;

function errorCallback(error){
    console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);   
}

/*
var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleSourceOpen, false);
var sourceBuffer;
*/

var mediaRecorder;
var chunks = [];
var count = 0;

function startRecording(stream) {
    log('Start recording...');
    if (typeof MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported == 'function'){
        /*
            MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported is a function announced in https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder and later introduced in the MediaRecorder API spec http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/
        */
        if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp9')) {
          var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'};
        } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=h264')) {
          var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264'};
        } else  if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp8')) {
          var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'};
        }
        log('Using '+options.mimeType);
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    }else{
        log('Using default codecs for browser');
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    }

    pauseResBtn.textContent = "Pause";

    mediaRecorder.start(10);

    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    videoElement.src = url ? url.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
    videoElement.play();

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
        //log('Data available...');
        //console.log(e.data);
        //console.log(e.data.type);
        //console.log(e);
        chunks.push(e.data);
    };

    mediaRecorder.onerror = function(e){
        log('Error: ' + e);
        console.log('Error: ', e);
    };


    mediaRecorder.onstart = function(){
        log('Started & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);
    };

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(){
        log('Stopped  & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);

        var blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: "video/mp4"});
        chunks = [];

        var videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        downloadLink.href = videoURL;
        videoElement.src = videoURL;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = 'Download video file';

        var rand =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000));
        var name  = "video_"+rand+".mp4" ;

        downloadLink.setAttribute( "download", name);
        downloadLink.setAttribute( "name", name);
    };

    mediaRecorder.onpause = function(){
        log('Paused & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);
    }

    mediaRecorder.onresume = function(){
        log('Resumed  & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);
    }

    mediaRecorder.onwarning = function(e){
        log('Warning: ' + e);
    };
}

//function handleSourceOpen(event) {
//  console.log('MediaSource opened');
//  sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp9"');
//  console.log('Source buffer: ', sourceBuffer);
//}

function onBtnRecordClicked (){
     if (typeof MediaRecorder === 'undefined' || !navigator.getUserMedia) {
        alert('MediaRecorder not supported on your browser, use Firefox 30 or Chrome 49 instead.');
    }else {
        navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, startRecording, errorCallback);
        recBtn.disabled = true;
        pauseResBtn.disabled = false;
        stopBtn.disabled = false;
    }
}

function onBtnStopClicked(){
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    videoElement.controls = true;

    recBtn.disabled = false;
    pauseResBtn.disabled = true;
    stopBtn.disabled = true;
}

function onPauseResumeClicked(){
    if(pauseResBtn.textContent === "Pause"){
        console.log("pause");
        pauseResBtn.textContent = "Resume";
        mediaRecorder.pause();
        stopBtn.disabled = true;
    }else{
        console.log("resume");
        pauseResBtn.textContent = "Pause";
        mediaRecorder.resume();
        stopBtn.disabled = false;
    }
    recBtn.disabled = true;
    pauseResBtn.disabled = false;
}


function log(message){
    dataElement.innerHTML = dataElement.innerHTML+'<br>'+message ;
}



//browser ID
function getBrowser(){
    var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
    var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
    var browserName  = navigator.appName;
    var fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
    var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
    var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

    // In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
    if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
     browserName = "Opera";
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+6);
     if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1)
       fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
    }
    // In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
     browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5);
    }
    // In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome"
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
     browserName = "Chrome";
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
    }
    // In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version"
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
     browserName = "Safari";
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
     if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1)
       fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
    }
    // In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox"
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
     browserName = "Firefox";
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
    }
    // In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent
    else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) <
           (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) )
    {
     browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);
     if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
      browserName = navigator.appName;
     }
    }
    // trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
    if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
       fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
    if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
       fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);

    majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10);
    if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
     fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
     majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
    }


    return browserName;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Note that this is a poor answer in itself. As soon as those links stop working some day, this answer is useless.